# how can I undo this mode in the unreal engine 4.27

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'm new to ue4 and while working on a project have clicked on something that turned the 3D viewspace which is movable with right click plus w,a,s,d, I changed some mode (I believe) so that it turned to a 2D space which I can move only right and left, up and down and zoom in or out, but cannot tilt the camera. TRight clich and drag gives me some measurement of distance I believe.

How do I return to the default mode of view in ue4?

Thank you all in advance!

below is the screenshot of how my editor looks like right now
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just accidentally changed your Viewport Mode.

It's as easy as clicking that little car button with the text that says "Back", which will open a dropdown. Then choose "Perspective" or whatever applies to you. It's at the top left corner of the viewport window, right below the "Save Current" button.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was trying to find the button + googling for 3 hours I think:)